# Firestore description language

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to prototype a data scheme on firestore, but i need to use the console to model all the schema

Use the firebase firestore console to model the data schema

Does firestore have a description language, so i can use and model my schema on a descriptive manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no modeling language provided by Google.  A description of the data modeling Firestore uses can be found in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model), which I'm sure you're already familiar with.  There is nothing more than what's described on that page.  In general, NoSQL databases tend to lack structure, other than what you impose in your code.  A document can contain essentially whatever you want, given the limits on the [types of fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) you can use.

Comment: If you found it helpful, please mark the answer as correct.